# Меню: открытие/закрытие по клику

Tags: меню, jquery, javascript

Здравствуйте, есть меню реализованное на JS. Работает оно при наведении с задержкой. Однако сейчас появилась необходимость переписать немного меню так, чтоб подпункты открывались по нажатию (клику).
Сам код JS выглядит так:

```
$('.menu li').mouseenter(function(){
    timer = setTimeout(function() {
                $('div.subs div.dl').slideDown(400);
}, 750);
}).mouseleave(function(){
             clearTimeout(timer);
            $('div.subs div.dl').slideUp(50);
});
});
```

отрисовывается меню следующим образом:

```
<div class="menuholder">
<ul class="menu slide">
  <?php foreach ($categories as $category) { ?>
  <li><a href="<?php echo $category['href']; ?>" class="orange"><h2><?php echo $category['name']; ?></h2></a>
<?php if ($category['children']) { ?>
  <?php for ($i = 0; $i < count($category['children']);) { ?>
  <div class="subs">
    <div class="dl effect6">
        <?php for ($i = 0; $i < count($category['children']); $i++) { ?>
          <?php if (isset($category['children'][$i])) { ?>
          <div class="item">
            <div>
              <a href="<?php echo $category['children'][$i]['href']; ?>"><img alt="<?php echo $category['children'][$i]['name']; ?>" src="<?php echo $category['children'][$i]['image']?>"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="link">
              <a href="<?php echo $category['children'][$i]['href']; ?>"><?php echo $category['children'][$i]['name']; ?></a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <?php } ?>
      <?php } ?>
    </div>
  </div>
  <?php } ?>
    <?php } ?>
  <?php } ?>
  </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Танки в бой! : )

    <?php } ?>
      <?php } ?>
    <?php } ?>

Comment: А можно код меню конечный, а не кусок шаблона?

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать так как написал *georg*, только скройте первоначально подменю(иначе будет работать наоборот), т.е.:

**css:**

```
div.subs div.dl{
    display:none;
}
```

**jquery:**

```
$('.menu li').on('click', function(){    
    $('div.subs div.dl').toggle("slow");
});
```

Рабочий пример:

```js
$('.menu li').on('click', function() {
  $('div.subs div.dl').toggle("slow");
});
```

```css
div.subs div.dl {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="menu">
  <li>test 1</li>
  <li>test 2</li>
  <li>test 3</li>
  <li>test 4</li>
</ul>
<div class="subs">
  <div class="dl">sdcsdcsdcdcsdcsdd</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Здравствуйте
попробуйте так

```
$('.menu li').on('click', function(){    
    $('div.subs div.dl').toggle("slow");
});
```

можете посмотреть рабочий пример здесь [jsfiddle.net/wnU9K/](http://jsfiddle.net/wnU9K/)

Comment: Закрытие выпадающего списка...